# jQuery using plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've just started using jquery plugins and I can't find a good resource on how to use the configurable options.  I'd like to use [this color picker](http://blog.meta100.com/post/600571131/mcolorpicker) but change it so that transparent isn't an option.  In the comments it says: `// $.fn.mColorPicker.init.allowTransparency - Turn off transperancy as a color option.` but I don't know how or when I'm supposed to be using that line.  Is there someplace that explains this?

Comment: Usually you'll load your plugin with options like this: `$('#div_id').mColorPicker({option1:"value1",option2:"value2"})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set that option any time *after* jQuery and the plugin are loaded (say, in a document ready handler), and *before* calling `$('whatever').mColorPicker()`.

```
$(function ()
{
    $.fn.mColorPicker.init.allowTransparency = false;
    $('whatever').mColorPicker();
});
```